# How to make unbound call using twilio?

Tags: android, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I want to make unbound call using twilio. Like I am dialling number from twilio voice start demo and receiving call on dial number but can't talk. There is only cassette speaking on caller and receiver side both.

I have done below things

1) Create backed api using PHP for get access token of my twilio account which help of that I can make call.

2) Create on makeCall php file and set it to **TwiML Apps**.

3) Added my number in verified numbers in twilio panel as I have trial account of twilio.

Problem is when I am calling through quick start application it is listening me one cassette but can talk with both receiver and caller.

Any one can help me on this then it would be helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

So, you've completed the quickstart and managed to make a call and get a recorded response.

That response was created with TwiML, specifically [`<Say>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/say). The PHP probably looks like this: `$response->say("Thanks for calling!");`

In order to connect to another caller, you need to use [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial). Replace the above `say` method with:

```
$response->dial("Number you wish to dial");
```

And try again, you should be connected through to the number you enter in the code.

Check out the [overview on TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml) and the voice tutorial section in the Twilio docs for more on how to control calls with TwiML.